# error: function pgp_sym_encrypt(bytea, text) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run a query from my nodejs app to update encrypted data into a column. However I am seeing the error below -

error: function pgp_sym_encrypt(unknown, unknown) does not exist

**query snippet**

```
        client.query('UPDATE application_test set content = pgp_sym_encrypt($2,$3) where application_id = $1', [appId, data, password], function (dbErr: any, result: any) {
            done();

            if (dbErr) {
                reject(dbErr);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
```

However the below sql works fine when I run using postgresql client :

```
update application_test set content = pgp_sym_encrypt('{"appId":"122345"}', 'password')
where application_id='122345';
```

**EDIT:** Turns out that I was running the query using client with my dba password. However from the code it is a different user which is connecting to same database. How can I make the pgp_sym_encrypt utility visible for othe users using the same database?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to explicitly type cast the call of you function like this

```
client.query('UPDATE application_test set content = pgp_sym_encrypt($2 ::text,$3 ::text) where application_id = $1', [appId, data, password], function (dbErr: any, result: any) {
   done();
   if (dbErr) {
      reject(dbErr);
   } else {
   resolve();
}
        });
```

> P.S. `pgp_sym_encryp` function is visible to all user.